# Установка интерпретатора Python в Neovim (WSL + Ubuntu Terminal)

Tags: python-3.x, vim, wsl

OS: Win10 Pro (+подсистема Линукс)

App: Neovim v.0.4.3 (использую с терминалом Ubuntu)

Поддержка Python 3 имеется (`:echo has('python3')`), все необходимое установлено, использую `coc.nvim` для авто-дополнения кода (+`coc-python`) и плагин `supertab`, при запуске файлов `.py` приходится начать вводить код, нажать Tab, подождать секунд 5, nvim начинает поиск интерпретатора, после жду еще немного, чтобы прошло сканирование тэгов, только после этого авто-дополнение можно спокойно использовать (автоматически ставит Python 3.8.2 64bit).

Ввел в терминале `whereis python3`, вывод:

> python3: /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3.8-config
> /usr/lib/python3.8 /usr/lib/python3 /etc/python3.8 /etc/python3
> /usr/local/lib/python3.8 /usr/include/python3.8
> /usr/include/python3.8m /usr/share/python3
> /mnt/c/Python36-32/python3.dll /mnt/c/Python36-32/python36.dll
> /mnt/c/Python38/python3.dll /mnt/c/Python38/python38.dll
> /mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/python3
> /usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz

Какую команду и путь к интерпретатору ввести в конфигурационном файле (init.vim)?